# Trailing spaces to complete a StringBuffer width (Java)

Tags: java, string

I would like to create a string that HAVE trailing spaces to complete a stringbuffer width.

e.g:

```
Stringbuffer str = new Stringbuffer(10);  //Create a string with 10 spaces.
str.append("Hello");
```

The output is 
"Hello" without any trailing spaces.
But what I want is "Hello" with 5 trailing spaces.

In the above example, since "Hello" has 5 characters, there should be 5 more trailing spaces after it.

Please advice, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append a space until the length is less than 10:

```
while(str.length() < 10) {
    str.append(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A StringBuffer implements Appendable. You could instantiate a Formatter object with this StringBuffer and then let the Formatter do the work for you:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  // I prefer StringBuilder to StringBuffer
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
formatter.format("%-10s", "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward

Hint :

1. A for loop, initialize iterator to length of string and loop it till it is 10.
2. Inside loop append a space to string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that right pads your String. You input the String then the int is for the pad needed.

`public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);

}`

You can get the String first, then append it to your StringBuffer (or StringBuilder).

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
Stringbuffer str = new Stringbuffer(10);  //Create a string with 10 spaces.
```

Does not create a string with 10 spaces. It actually create a string with capacity 10.
You can see the java doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

For the answer, you can follow some of the answer above, like append spaces after the hello, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers say how to solve your problem.  I just want to point out a misunderstanding in the question.

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(10);  //Create a string with 10 spaces.
```

In fact, that is NOT what the StringBuffer (or StringBuilder) constructor argument means.  What it is actually doing is specifying an *initial capacity*.  This is essentially a hint to the implementation to initially allocate space for 10 characters.

- It does not *set* the actual size of the content.  The actual size is determined by how many characters you put into the buffer / builder.
- It does not *limit* the size of the buffer / builder.  If you add more than 10 characters, the implementation quietly and efficiently expands the buffer / builder's backing storage.

(Also, unless you *need* a thread-safe buffer, it is better to use `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer`.)